# How to return all values (horizontal array) in B that has the same key stored in A?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, pivot

Sample `Sheet 1`:

```
  A   B
1 a   x
2 a   y
3 a   z
4 b   i
5 b   h
6 b   w
```

---

Formula result, in `Sheet 2`, I am looking for:

```
  A   B   C   D
1 a   x   y   z
2 b   i   h   w
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
={UNIQUE(FILTER('Sheet 1'!A1:A, 'Sheet 1'!A1:A<>"")),
  ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(
  QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(TRANSPOSE(
  QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
  QUERY({'Sheet 1'!A1:B}, "select count(Col1) 
                           where Col1 !='' 
                           group by Col1 
                           pivot Col2", 0)),
                          "select Col2, Col3", 0))>=1, 
  QUERY({'Sheet 1'!A1:B}, "select count(Col1) 
                           where Col1 !='' 
                           group by Col1 
                           pivot Col2 
                           limit 0"), ))&"♥", , 
  COLUMNS(TRANSPOSE(A2:B)))), "♥ "))}
```

[image]

Comment: Just curious, what the green hearts do? It seems to work without them.

Comment: just for cuteness :) in some cases may not work without them but they can be changed for any symbol (should be unique symbol)

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on [user0](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/186471/user0)'s solution, because I had a similar issue but with two precise differences

1. I had a lot more than 2 distinct values in column A - over 200 in fact

The key is in the `"select Col2, Col3"` statement, which needs to be expanded. Replacing this with `"select Col"&textjoin(", Col",,sequence(countunique(A:A),1,2))` enables this solution to work for as many results as you need.

2. My column A was not sorted

This I solved by wrapping the initial `UNIQUE()` statement with a `SORT()`

[EDIT] Upon review, I discovered that there was something weird about the way it was sorting, leading to a mismatch but in only a couple of places. For some reason the query sorted the list below differently from the way `SORT()` does, placing the last item at the start.

26-IG-Sci-9Sci1, 26-IG-Sci-9Sci2, 26-IG-Sci-9Sci3, 26-IG-SPA-9 Spa

The solution was to change the Select statement to this

`select Col1, count(Col1) where Col1 !='' group by Col1 pivot Col2 order by Col1`

For what it's worth, my issue was a list of classIDs and teacher email addresses - some classes have more than one teacher assigned to them. I then needed to concatenate these into a single cell - for which I used the Query Smush concept which I found outlined [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/186471/user0)